# How to integrate two Symfony projects that are on different servers?

Tags: symfony

I have two symfony projects and that share the same database servers.

I would like to, if possible, from one project call some Entity/Repository of another. The problem is:

Both project are in different servers.

So, is there some way to, maybe using services, make the projects talk to each other?

I tried to create a service passing SERVER IP + folder directory but it returns an error like:

what i did:

```yaml
Ia\:
    resource: "ftp://172.21.0.6/src/"
```

what returns:

`Warning: file_exists(): connect() failed: Connection refused in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short anwser: no**. You cannot use php classes of another project hosted on another host.

What you could do:

- Talk http: Expose functionality of project A in api endpoints and call those endpoints from project B.
- Introduce your own library: Factor out common functionality into a third project, namely a library that you install in both projects (using composer).

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Actually, I have one library that are used in both projects. But I really have not idea how to take an class and "expose" it to other projects.